# Free movement between the US and Compact of Free Association countries

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, marshall-islands

There is an [arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_of_Free_Association) for citizens of the three Pacific Island sovereign states of the Federated States of Micronesia (FSM), the Republic of the Marshall Islands (RMI), and the Republic of Palau, to travel visa-free and live and work in the US indefinitely.

This applies to citizens who are:

"...citizens from birth or independence, and to naturalized citizens who have resided in the Federated States of Micronesia (FSM), the Republic of the Marshall Islands or Palau for at least five years, excluding those who acquired citizenship by investment." [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_States#General_exemption)

My question is that if someone becomes a citizen by means of investment, how do the Immigration officers know about that at the time of entry to the US, since they can travel visa-free? I don't think passports mention who became a citizen by what method.

Comment: I speculate that the free movement treaties contain some requirement that the island nations tell the US about specific classes of citizenship.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Meanwhile I continued my research on this and I think there is no clear instruction about this but I have found a [document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/fact-sheets/FactSheet-Status_of_Citizens_of_Micronesia_Marshalls_Islands.pdf) that discusses how those countries' Governments have to share list of people resident for 5 years or more. So I think your speculation is correct that those Island nations would share the information to the US in some way which is not clearly written on the internet. Should I delete this question?

Comment: it is not just passport. Probably the listed countries shares also other information about own citizen. Visa-free but still an immigration control (like any US citizen should do, coming from abroad).

Comment: @JayShah no please share what you've found as an answer, this is very interesting, I'm surprised nobody upvoted the question.